# what kind of data is the radius in minEnclosingCircle opencv

Tags: python, opencv, radius

I'm using the minEnclosingCircle function in openCV and need to perform an analysis of the different radius I get back. So if I have a circle with a radius of 20, what does it mean? 20 pixel?

Comment: yes, what else could it be?

Comment: @Miki i don't know, mm?